# await vs asyncio.run() in Python

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

In Python, what is the actual difference between `await`ing a coroutine and using `asyncio.run()`? They both seem to run a coroutine, the only difference that I can see being that `await` can only be used in a coroutine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is the exact difference. There should be exactly one call to `asyncio.run()` in your code, which will block until all coroutines have finished.

Inside any coroutine, you can use `await` to suspend the current function, and `asyncio` will resume the function at some future time. All of this happens inside the `asyncio.run()` function, which schedules what functions can run when.